# UWP How to animate movement?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a method that animates the position of a marker on a boardgame. If players rolls the dice and the dice return 4, then marker is moved to a specific position on the board. The animation works fine.

However, the marker moves in a straight line - I would like the marker to move through all the position until it reach the end position.

Here is my int[,]

```
this.Path = new int[,] { { 0, 0 },{ 40, 50 }, { 95, 45 }, {130,0 }, { 110,-60 }, { 60, -100 }, { 0,-140 }, { -40, -200 }, { -30,-280 }};
```

It holds the X and Y position relative to startposition(margin).

And the animation method - how can I change it so the player rolls eg. 2 it should animate position 0 and 1 on the array.

```
 private void AnimatePlayerMovement(Player player, int eyes)
        {
            //This will hold hour animation
            Piece.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

            //New storyboard
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

            //New DoubleAnimation - Y
            DoubleAnimation translateYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            translateYAnimation.From = this.Path[player.position - eyes , 1];
            translateYAnimation.To = this.Path[player.position , 1];

            translateYAnimation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase();
            translateYAnimation.EasingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;
            translateYAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(translateYAnimation, Piece);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
            storyboard.Children.Add(translateYAnimation);

            //New DoubleAnimation - X 
            DoubleAnimation translateXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            translateXAnimation.From = this.Path[player.position - eyes, 0];
            translateXAnimation.To = this.Path[player.position, 0];

            //translateXAnimation.From = this.Path[player.position - eyes, 0];
            //translateXAnimation.To = this.Path[player.position, 0];
            translateXAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(translateXAnimation, Piece);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateXAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");

            storyboard.Children.Add(translateXAnimation);

            //executing the storyboard
            storyboard.Begin();

        }
```

Comment: uhh, like the sound of that - I will take a look at it

Comment: Question : And the path can be interupted?

Comment: I have an idea. But it will look ugly and should be used if no other option is available. Let's see if anyone can give a better idea.

Comment: true - any other ssuggestions?

Comment: if the dice rolls to 6 , is the marker expected to move through 6 points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's an ugly solution. It will work playing animation sequentially, one after one.

Let's assume the Marker is a `Rectangle`, so, we add some animation on it's `TranslateX` and `TranslateY`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="PathAnimationStory" 
                Completed="Story_Completed">
        
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="anim_x" 
                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="TargetTranform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"/>
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="anim_y" 
                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="TargetTranform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Rectangle
    Width="50"
    Height="50"
    Fill="Red"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TargetTranform" X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Notice the `Completed` event handled in the `Storyboard`. We need to chain the animation. To do that, handle the `Completed` event when the animation stops, it will check if any other points are to be gone through and start the animation again if any:

```
private void MoveMarker(params double[] co_ordinates)
{
    PathAnimationStory.Stop();

    if (co_ordinates.Length == 0)
        return;
    /// the number of co_ordinates must be even
    if (co_ordinates.Length % 2 == 1)
        return;

    Co_ordinates = co_ordinates;
    remaining_nodes = co_ordinates.Length / 2;

    Story_Completed(default, default);
}

private void Story_Completed(object sender, object e)
{
    if(remaining_nodes > 0)
    {
        int next_node = (int)(Co_ordinates.Length / 2 - remaining_nodes);
        anim_x.To = Co_ordinates[2 * next_node];
        anim_y.To = Co_ordinates[2 * next_node + 1];
        remaining_nodes--;

        PathAnimationStory.Begin();
    }
}
```

All done, now let's check our code:

```
MoveMarker(100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0);
```

gives this output:

[image]

Which I think somewhat meets your requirement.
Hope that helps.